# TypeError when Django authenticate function tries to bind to custom authenticate function

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

I am attempting to implement an authentication method where:

- the user submits their email
- I generate a token for that user that is stored in the database, or I retrieve the token if it already exists
- I generate a link to log in and email it to the user, with the token as an HTTP parameter
- The token is extracted from the link and used to search for an active user
- The user info is passed to the template

Note that this isn't for any mission-critical production software - I'm reading the Obey The Testing Goat O'Reilly book and this is the authentication method the author has us implement.

So when the user clicks the link in their email, this is the view function that handles it:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
    uid = request.GET.get('uid')
    user = authenticate(uid=uid)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
    return redirect('/')
```

In that view function, we call the `authenticate` function that is provided by `django.contrib.auth`. Here is that function:

```
def authenticate(request=None, **credentials):
    """
    If the given credentials are valid, return a User object.
    """
    for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True):
        backend_signature = inspect.signature(backend.authenticate)
        try:
            backend_signature.bind(request, **credentials)
        except TypeError:
            # This backend doesn't accept these credentials as arguments. Try the next one.
            
            ### I have confirmed that the bind function above, and specifically the _bind private function, 
            ### is throwing the TypeError so my custom auth function is never getting called
            
            continue
        try:
            user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
        except PermissionDenied:
            # This backend says to stop in our tracks - this user should not be allowed in at all.
            break
        if user is None:
            continue
        # Annotate the user object with the path of the backend.
        user.backend = backend_path
        return user
```

Note that this is Django framework code - I did not write this. For some reason, the line `backend_signature.bind(request, **credentials)` is throwing a `TypeError` so my custom auth function is not getting called. (I've confirmed this with print statements)

Here is the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` from `settings.py`. The `_get_backends` function in the `for` statement looks for this setting to determine what auth backend should be used. I can confirm that it finds my custom backend - for some reason the parameters passed in just aren't able to bind to it:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'accounts.authentication.PasswordlessAuthenticationBackend',
]
```

And here is the actual custom backend code:

```
    def authenticate(self, uid):
        if not Token.objects.filter(uid=uid).exists():
            return None
        token = Token.objects.get(uid=uid)
        try:
            user = ListUser.objects.get(email=token.email)
            return user
        except ListUser.DoesNotExist:
            return ListUser.objects.create(email=token.email)
```

Thanks in advance for any help - let me know if there is more information I can give.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

My authentication function needed to take a request parameter, because a request parameter, with a default of `None`, was being cascaded down from the Django `authenticate` function.

So my custom authentication function signature looks like this:

```
authenticate(self, request, uid)
```